# A Peculiar Incident with a System Call Tracer

Tags: linux, operating-system, system-calls, execve

I'm writing a basic system call tracer. Its basic operation is to spawn a child, intercept its system calls, count them up, and dump the results to a file after the child has closed.

I'm testing the tracer with common terminal programs. Oddly, sometimes it will count multiple **execve** calls in a row as soon as the child process is spawned. For instance, when I test the program on **ls**, the system call tracer counts seven execve just after ls is spawned. However, when I test the system call tracer on **\bin\ls** (with no other changes), the system call tracer will count just one execve call, as it should have in the case above.

Why am I getting different counts? Is the shell making calls I am unaware of?